# Как наиболее эффективно представить код Pascal на C++?

Tags: c++, pascal, соревнование

```
var k, l, m, n: integer;
begin
  readln(k,l,m,n);
  if (k+l+m+n mod 2 = 0) then
    writeln('поля одного цвета')
  else
    writeln('поля разных цветов')
end.
```

Answer (score 12):

http://ideone.com/yFmnDU

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define var int
#define begin {
#define end ;}
#define readln [](var&a, var&b, var&c, var&d){cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;}
#define if if(
#define mod )%
#define then 
#define else ;else
#define writeln puts

var main()
begin
  var k, l, m, n;
  begin
    readln(k,l,m,n);
    if (k+l+m+n mod 2 == 0) then
      writeln("поля одного цвета")
    else
      writeln("поля разных цветов")
  end
end
```

Comment: а можно макрос `readln` пояснить, что означает `[&]` перед параметрами.

Comment: @pavel, лямбда-функция с захватом всего по ссылке. Перемудрил. Сначала хотел без параметров сделать, но запятые помешали.

Comment: @pavel, и вообще, там баг был... Исправил.

Comment: Жалко что рекурсивный макрос не поддерживается, я так хотел `#define __read(A,x...) >> A __read(x)
#define read(A,x...) cin >> A __read(x)`

Comment: Cool! C++ подрос в моих глазах :)

Comment: @pavel, а если шаблонную функцию, а не макрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy `bool read() {
    return false;
}
template<typename... T>
bool read(auto &a, T&... tail) {
 cin >> a;
    return cin.fail() || read(tail...);
}` так или проще можно?

Comment: с такими ответчиками бедная девка-то будет:D Зачет

Comment: @Qwertiy: Отлично! :-D

Comment: @pavel, а зачем fail проверять?

Comment: @Qwertiy а привычка, если что-то не прочитали то дальше тоже не читать, исключение не стал кидать.

Answer (score 4):

```
int k, l, m, n;
cin >> k >> l >> m >> n;
cout << "поля "<< (k^l^m^n&1 ? "разных цветов":"одного цвета")<<endl;
```

Мне так больше нравится :)

Comment: Я ждал подобного варианта. Краткость - сестра таланта ;)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, можно было загуглить функции из C++ и примеры их написания. Код не слишком сильно изменился бы :)

```
int k, l, m, n;
scanf("%d%d%d%d", &k, &l, &m, &n);
if((k + l + m + n) % 2 == 0)
    printf("поля одного цвета");
else
    printf("поля разных цветов");
```

Comment: Ну у вас скорее Pure C.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int k(0), l(0), m(0), n(0);

    cin >> k >> l >> m >> n;
    if ((k + l + m + n) % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "поля одного цвета" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "поля разных цветов" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```