# Единый код (для расчета цены) на JS и PHP

Tags: php, javascript

На чем можно записать алгоритм, который должен отрабатывать единым образом в JS и в PHP (чтобы избежать дублирования кода)?

На сайте есть код, который рассчитывает стоимость заказа. Стоимость зависит от многих параметров, которые выбираются посетителем на сайте. Посетителю демонстрируется итоговая стоимость, которая рассчитывается с помощью JS. Потом параметры заказа отправляются на сервер.

На сервере (php) расчет стоимости по заданным параметрам происходит заново, для оформления заказа и записи в БД.

Получается дублирование кода - один и тот же алгоритм реализован и на JS, и на PHP. При изменении приходится вносить правки и туда, и туда. Это проблема.

Получать стоимость  с сервера через AJAX во время изменения параметров пользователем нельзя, так как это происходит несколько раз в секунду (посетитель перетаскивает ползунок и в зависимости от его положения изменяется стоимость).

Вопрос в том, как записать этот алгоритм расчета в коде, едином и для JS и для PHP. Я уже думал использовать [v8js](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php), но на хостингах такое пока не поддерживается.

Что еще можно попробовать для описания алгоритма, чтобы это можно было выполнять и в PHP, и в JS без изменений?

Comment: "При изменении приходится вносить правки и туда, и туда. Это проблема." - сколько по времени занимает перенос правок алгоритма и как часто он происходит?

Comment: В гугле нашлось такое: https://github.com/sstur/js2php

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, проблема ж не во времени, а в том, что где-то что-то забываешь и они начинают работать по-разному...

Comment: @Qwertiy, я просто предлагаю автору немного правильно оценить риски различных решений. Стремление к идеалу - это хорошо, но бывает что овчинка ну совсем выделки не стоит.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, главное не забыть учесть время на фикс багов вида "я форму отправляю, а она не отправляется" ;)

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Не то чтобы часто требуются правки, скорее часто нужно создавать новые формулы. Это акции. Вы знаете, как сейчас работает маркетинг: на каждый информационный повод они запускают акцию. И вот уже два разных человека пишут код на разных языках (который должен работать одинаково), допуская в нем разные ошибки. В процессе отладки им требуется синхронно вносить правки. Как-то так и возник этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Решение "в обход" — выкидывание реализации на JS

"Каноническая" реализация на сервере однозначно должна быть, так что выкинуть можно только если реализацию на JS, вместо неё получать результат с сервера.

#### Решение "в лоб" — язык над обоими

Мне известен ровно один язык, способный собираться и в JS, и в PHP — [**Haxe**](http://haxe.org/). Но это добавление в проект ещё одного языка. Стоит ли оно того?

#### Решение "боком" — преобразовать одну в другую

Если алгоритм использует совсем мало фич языка, преобразовать одно в другое может быть возможно даже регулярными выражениями. Тут народ [Паскаль в Си переводит препроцессором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523819/181100), может и у вас получится. Но этот костыль, скорее всего, будет одноразовым и после сколько-нибудь существенных правок потребует доработки. Повезёт ещё, если сообщит о проблемах преобразования (хотя бы падением результата), а не просто по-тихому поведёт себя иначе.

Comment: А XSLT не умеет такого? Или он в JS все еще не доступен?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov что-то я сильно сомневаюсь, что XSLT может представить алгоритм ТСа. Но ваша идея, как я понимаю, заключается в том, чтобы взять реализации одного и того же, условно, **интерпретатора** на двух разных языках?

Comment: @D-side еще можно из php вызывать v8 и иметь алгоритм на js )

Comment: @Nofate это упомянуто в вопросе, ага :)

Comment: @D-side, что-то там считают на XSLT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389089/arithmetic-operation-in-xslt

Comment: @AlexanderZonov oh shi~

Comment: Haxe. Прекрасно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Ну если захотеть извратиться, то можно замутить что-нибудь такое:

```
var calculate = (function () {
  var $q, $res;
  return function calculate //<?php function calculate
    ($base, $percent, $n) {
      $res = $base;
      $percent = 1 + $percent / 100;

      for ($q=0; $q<$n; ++$q) {
        $res *= $percent;
      }

      return $res;
    }

  $q
  -->0;/*
})(); //*/
```

Впрочем, предварительно надо убедиться в поддержке браузерами комментария `-->`, который официально появляется только в ES6.

- JS: https://jsfiddle.net/us9m5n3g/1/
- PHP: http://ideone.com/ByU8Cs

PS: А вообще, Node.js :)

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что можно написать код, который будет корректно выполняться и в js, и в php за счет похожести синтаксиса?

Comment: @cronfy, ага. Хотя это скорее шутка, чем реальное предложение. Но в принципе, такое возможно.